# Inequalities $x^2+5x+c<0$ and $-x^2-5x-c<0$

Tags: inequality

> The solution of $x^2+5x+c<0$ is the interval $(-7;2)$. What is the solution of $-x^2-5x-c<0$.

I am trying to solve the problem but I don't have experience with inequalities. I guess I should try to use that in the left sides of the inequalities we have opposite expressions. How should I approach the problem? Can you give me a hint? Thank you in advance!

Comment: First hint would be to solve for c using the fact that boundaries of interval (-7,2) must be roots of $x^2+5x+c$. (Why?)

Comment: Notice that, equivalently, you are trying to find those $x$ that satisfy $x^2+5x+c > 0$. Those are exactly the points outside $(-7,2)$

Answer (score 1):

The solution set of $x^2+5x+c<0$ is $(-7,2)$. If you are familiar with parabolas, then the graph of parabola $y=x^2+5x+c$ is under $x$-axis when $x\in(-7,2)$. It means that $$x^2+5x+c=(x+7)(x-2)=x^2+5x-14$$
i.e. $c=-14$.

But we don't need the exact value of $c$. The inequality $-x^2-5x-c<0$ or equivalently $x^2+5x+c>0$ is the segments of the same parabola above $x$-axis. Therefore the solution set is $$(-\infty,-7)\cup(2,\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. $-x^2-5x-c<0$ implies $x^2+5x+c>0$. Can you complete now?